# C++ Why does 'note: see reference to class template instantiation being compiled'

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, gcc

in an .hpp file, I have a template function which is member of class.

```
class BLog
{
  public:
    enum { LOG_ERROR, LOG_WARN, LOG_STATUS, LOG_INFO, LOG_NOTICE, LOG_DEBUG };

    template <typename... Args>
    void appLog(int prio, const char *fmt, Args const &... args);
    template <typename... Args>
    void appLogError(const char *fmt, Args const &... args) { this->appLog(LOG_ERROR, fmt, args...);  } 
}
```

When calling this,

```
int main() 
{
    BLog myLog();

    myLog.appLog(BLog::LOG_ERROR, "%s message", "Test");
}
```

I am getting the warning as

> note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void
>   myLog::appLog(int,const char *,const char (&)[5])' being
>   compiled

Can't figure out the proper syntax to pass arguments...

Hope someone can help.Thanks in advance.

**Rem:** With the proposed answer, using Visual Studio, I always have the warning with the `W4` flag.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to "fix" the code in a way that makes a correct answer no longer applicable. If you want to know about the warning you get after making that change, open a second question about the warning. (Be sure to post code that generates the same warning, and say exactly what the text of the warning actually is.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `BLog myLog();` is a function declaration. Use `BLog myLog{};`.
2. `myLog::LOG_ERROR` should be `BLog::LOG_ERROR`.

Comment: Simple variable declaration `BLog myLog;`.

Comment: @S.M., sure, in the present case it's possible. But in the general case `BLog myLog;` and `BLog myLog{};` might be not equivalent.

Comment: updated. Whith `myLog{};` & `BLog myLog;` get same error.

Comment: @LeMoussel, after the update neither this answer nor the linked one make any sense, please don't do such updates. As to your error, I can't reproduce it: https://godbolt.org/z/Tjyl-v

Comment: @Evg. OK. I use Visual Studio.
And unfortunately, I can't find the answer in "error: request for member '..' in '..' which is of non-class type"

Comment: @LeMoussel, I checked in VS, too. No error. Is the code you're trying to compile the same as in your question? Please post the complete error message. Maybe the error is somewhere else.

Comment: @Evg OK with the /W3 flag, but with /W4 I have this warning. `cl /MDd /W4 /EHsc /ZI /Od test.cpp /link /out:test.exe`

Comment: @LeMoussel, what is the warning number? Show the complete message, not just the *note*.

Comment: so much for me, it's not _warning_ message but _note_ message. I'm trying to understand the reason for this _note_ message.

Comment: @LeMoussel, I've never seen such *note*s **alone**, usually they accompany other information from the compiler. I can't reproduce this *note* alone in my VS, so I strongly suspect that either you're trying to compile different code or you don't see the full warning message from the compiler. If these are not the cases, sorry, I don't know why you see this note alone.

Comment: @Evg, You're absolutely right. 
I have before this _warning_ message `warning C4100: 'prio': unreferenced formal parameter` that I wasn't paying attention to. 
I resolve this _warning_ message, I no longer have the _note_ message.
Thank you very much for your help.